# Print rows that meet multiple if statements in Python

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement

**AIM**

I would like to print the entire rows of the file **master** that meet certain conditions.

**PROBLEM**

Before, I had

```
if rank <= 50 and price <= 10000:
```

instead of

```
if np.any(rank <= 50) and np.any(price <= 10000):
```

but I was getting the error:
**ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**

and I don't believe the use of a.any() is appropriate as it would return a boolean. I'm also struggling to understand how I can only print the rows of **master** that meet those conditions.

Thanks in advance for your help and explanations!

Here's the data:

```
1,11,10950
2,14,11000
3,15,10500
5,18,9750
6,19,9045
7,19,9945
8,19,9945
9,20,9250
10,21,7850
11,22,10620
12,26,9700
13,28,9300
14,29,9000
15,50,7170
16,53,9200
17,58,9085
18,63,8570
19,67,7920
20,75,6900
21,86,6085
23,130,5750
```

```
import numpy as np

master = np.loadtxt('master.txt', delimiter=',')

uni = master[:, 0]
rank = master[:, 1]
price = master[:, 2]


if np.any(rank <= 50) and np.any(price <= 10000):
    print("Print rows that meet conditions")
```

Comment: Once you have a valid Boolean array use [Boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)

Comment: In your first problem, you're comparing an array of strings to integers.

Comment: You may want to use [`np.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html#numpy.logical_and) or `&` instead of `and`

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html?highlight=warning#comparison-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments to your questions, use a combination of boolean arrays and `np.logical_and` to index the rows which satisfy your conditions.

```
import numpy as np

master = np.loadtxt('master.txt', delimiter=',')

print(master[np.logical_and(master[:, 0] <= 50, master[:, 2] <= 10000)])
```

Comment: How can I make the print display be an integer instead of scientific notation? 
I've tried ```np.set_printoptions(precision=int)``` but I'm getting the error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'

Comment: @Joehat Setting `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` will suppress scientific notation. Note that if you want to use the `precision` argument you have to set an actual integer, such as `np.set_printoptions(precision=3)`.